# ERROR - The specified data type is not valid. [ Data type (if known) = varchar ]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce

I have recently installed SQL 2008 R2

```
CREATE TABLE TPERSONS(
personid int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
lastname varchar(50) NULL,
firstname varchar(50) NULL,
salary money NULL,
managerid int NULL -- foreign key to personid
)
```

I do not understand why I receive this error.

```
Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 26302

)
The specified data type is not valid. [ Data type (if known) = varchar ]
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ded97).  What line is producing this error?

Comment: That executes fine on 2008r2 here. Your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Are you running this in SQL Server?

Comment: That error message is SQL Server CE AFAIK.

Answer (score 18):

The data type `varchar` is not one of the [supported data types on SQL Server CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). You must use `nvarchar`.

Note that `date` is not supported, either. Use `datetime` instead.

Comment: Also if your using <date> it won't works so, instead of <date> use <datetime>